# Trouble with Android - Calendar.get() returning the wrong value

Tags: android

I have seen other posts regarding the way Calendar objects work on Android/Java and I'm aware of the 0 based nature of the way it works. This issue seems (to me) to be different so I've posted a new question. Forgive me if it's a dupe.

I'm having an issue with returning an array which I've populated with the month/year of every month upto 1 year ago. For example the desired outcome is:

- July 2013
- June 2013
- May 2013
- ...
- August 2012

`PastMonth` is a simple object consisting of two integers, month/year and a string representation - "July 2013".

```
Calendar rightNow = Calendar.getInstance();

PastMonth[] dateList = new PastMonth[12];
dateList[0] = new PastMonth(rightNow.get(Calendar.MONTH), rightNow.get(Calendar.YEAR));
for (int i=1; i<=11; i++) {
    Calendar monthsAgo = Calendar.getInstance();
    int month = monthsAgo.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    monthsAgo.set(Calendar.MONTH, month - i);
    dateList[i] = new PastMonth(monthsAgo.get(Calendar.MONTH), monthsAgo.get(Calendar.YEAR));
}
```

This all works fine apart from February. I end up with January, and then 2 entries for March. So:

- ...
- April 2013
- **March 2013**
- **March 2013**
- January 2013
- December 2012
- ...

I'm confused why this is happening because if I place a watch on the `monthsAgo` object I can see the month value is set to 1, which is February due to the `Calendar` object being a 0 based array, but when I call `monthsAgo.get(Calendar.MONTH)` it's return 2. Otherwise the rest of the array looks fine and is the desired outcome.

I might have missed something simple here, I suspect it's something to do with January being 0 and February being 1 but I can't piece it together.

Comment: You probably want to move away from java's built in calendar asap. I strongly recommend joda-time.

Comment: Honestly this is the only time I've ever had to use it. Android is a part time thing for me at work, if and when projects for apps come up. I will look into Joda-Time though I have seen it mentioned elsewhere too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `monthsAgo.set(Calendar.MONTH, month - i);`, try `monthsAgo.add(Calendar.MONTH, -i);`. The issue is that (if you're executing it right now), you're ending up with February 29th, 2013 (internally), which becomes March 1, once everything is normalized. You'll want to look at the documentation for Calendar with its `set`, `add`, and `roll` methods, but in this case, I think `add` is what you want.

Comment: Heh, so my code would have worked once every 4 years, or at least any day of the month < 29th. Working as intended now, thank you.